# Want to set the first line number as "2"

Tags: numbering, listings

My tags are as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}{%
% Line numbers
numbers=left,
stepnumber=3,
firstnumber=2
}

\lstnewenvironment{shorttexcode}{\lstset{style=mylatexstyle}}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{shorttexcode}
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
\end{shorttexcode}


\end{document}
```

I need to start the line numbers from `2` and the following numbers are like as `5, 8, 11`, ...

But the line number does not change even I mentioned as `firstnumber=2`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: If I run your code snippet, the first line is number 2 (logically), but only the lines 3, 6 and 9 have a number. What output do you get?

Comment: Do you want `\renewcommand*\thelstnumber{\the\numexpr2+3*(\value{lstnumber}-1)\relax}%` with `stepnumber=1, firstnumber=1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For complicated numbering systems I would redefine `\thelstnumber`. That's more flexible than the inbuild options (I'm not quite sure that I understood the numbering you want, but you can adapt this to your needs).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}{%
% Line numbers
numbers=left,
}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\newcommand\setmynumberstyle[2]
{% #1=start #2=step
 \renewcommand*\thelstnumber
  {
   \int_compare:nF
    {\c@lstnumber < #1}
    { \int_compare:nT
       { \int_mod:nn {\c@lstnumber -#1} {#2} = 0 }
       { \arabic{lstnumber}}
    } 
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lstnewenvironment{shorttexcode}{\setmynumberstyle{2}{3}\lstset{style=mylatexstyle}}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{shorttexcode}
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
\end{shorttexcode}


\end{document}
```

### Edit

Rereading the question, you perhaps want an offset:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mylatexstyle}{%
% Line numbers
numbers=left,
}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\newcommand\setmynumberstyle[3]
{% #1=start #2=step #3 offset
 \renewcommand*\thelstnumber
  {
   \int_compare:nF
    {\c@lstnumber < #1}
    { \int_compare:nT
       { \int_mod:nn {\c@lstnumber -#1} {#2} = 0 }
       { \int_eval:n{ \c@lstnumber + #3 }}
    } 
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lstnewenvironment{shorttexcode}{\setmynumberstyle{1}{3}{1}\lstset{style=mylatexstyle}}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{shorttexcode}
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
\end{shorttexcode}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added a variant with an offset.

Answer (score 1):

add `numberfirstline=true` as described here: http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf section **5.6 Line numbers**

Comment: No, this gives 2,3,6,9... while the question asks for starting with 2 and increasing by three: 2,5,8,11...

Comment: @campa looks like this is a missing feature in the package. So my answer is the closesd the OP can get.